# Concatenating two variables in xslt (non-numeric and/or numeric)

Tags: xslt

i have two variables in xslt,i am not able to add those and assign to another variable,
Any help would be appreciated.

```
<xsl:variable name="Book" select="hummpty" />
<xsl:variable name="Book1" select="andro" />
<xsl:variable name="Total">
<xsl:value-of select="$Book + $Book1/>
</xsl:variable>
```

When i try to print 'Total' i am getting value as NaN.
How do i achieve this? After achieving this , i would like to assign this as an attribute value.
eg:

```
<Book totakBook="$Total" />
```

Something like above.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do both variables have a meaningful integer value?

Comment: What is the desired output of your example? If you intend to sum numeric values why does your example contain NaN values?

Comment: The variables may or may not contain integers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you actually want to concatenate string values, try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($Book, $Book1)" />
```

Comment: Wow, StackExchange amazes me. There are people who realize that when someone says he wants to add two values, he actually wants to concatenate them. That's pure mind-reading - brilliant.

Comment: @MichaelKay I prefer to call it "educated guesses" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <xsl:value-of select="sum($Book + $Book1)"/>
```

provided both variables contain valid numeric values.

Comment: The variables may or may not contain integers values, it is dynamic